# Creating a library application - which method to use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was hoping to get some advice. I want to create an application which is like a library that holds a lot of different information including documents, pics etc where a user can log in and search for different topics and see the definition of terminology. For example users would be able to click on the word 'electical current' and a definition of electrical current would appear with also links to supporting information. The user will not be allowed to edit any information only read it.

I am wondering what is the best language to use to do this? I know that storing all the information in a html file is definitely not the way to go. But I am not sure what to use - whether html linked to a database is a good option (I've heard that this is also not great because your database code is still accessible) or whether ror is a good option. I decided that ror would be a good framework to use but I still have some doubts such as:

1. the application will not be hosted on the internet but only on an intranet would ror still be good for this?
2. the 'site' is basically static except for a few users who will have admin access although it may have more user specific functions later on.

Any advice would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that a wiki type system would be fit for your purposes. You can create one without writing any code by using a free service such as [Google Sites](http://sites.google.com).

Comment: Google Sites is a closed application (source is not available).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Finbarr that your problem statement sounds like it could be solved by a wiki.

I suggest [mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) since it is open source--you can add to it or change the core software if necessary.

Or any other opensource wiki could be used. See [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_wiki_software)

Re: which language: your problem statement is pretty broad. From what you've told us, any language would do.

Best advice: find the open source wiki that most closely meets your needs and then learn the language that it was developed in. Usually that's php or perl. But you can also find Ruby on Rails wikis such as [Instiki](http://www.instiki.org/show/HomePage)

Added: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Note that your question is quite broad. So it may get closed for not being specific enough. Stack Overflow is aimed at answering specific questions about software programming. See the faq.